# Profile model Data is not saving when I try to create user and Profile simultaneously

Tags: django, django-forms

When I try to create a new user, I also want to create their profile at the same time. But there is no data coming from the Profile form. User is created but in Profile creation form I am getting an error.
Here is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   StudentID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='SID')
   image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.Branch
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       img = Image.open(self.image.path)
       if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
           output_size = (300, 300)
           img.thumbnail(output_size)
           img.save(self.image.path)
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProfileCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['StudentID', 'Branch', 'YearOfStudy', 'ContactNumber']
```

views.py
when I try to print StudentID, I get None value. I think there is data loss.

```
def register(request):
    print("hello")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        form1 = ProfileCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            StudentID = form.cleaned_data.get('StudentID')
            print(StudentID)
            profile = form1.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            form.save()
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            print("reached here")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        form1 = ProfileCreationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form1': form1
    }
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', context)
```

register.html

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">JOIN TODAY</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                {{ form1|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">Already have an account?<a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a></small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`StudentID` is on `form1` not `form`

```
StudentID = form1.cleaned_data.get('StudentID')
print(StudentID)
```

You should also save the `User` first since it's a required relation for the `Profile` model

```
user = form.save()
profile = form1.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```

Comment: I tried this, When I try to print profile.StudentID, it gives correct output
but in database nothing is saved
moreover I am getting an error whenever I try to create a new user
IntegrityError at /register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile.user_id

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Iain has pointed out, I think your code in the views has some problem after you run is_valid. Try to fix it like this:

```
if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():    
    profile = form1.save(commit=False)
    user = form.save()
    profile.user = user
    profile.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
    return redirect('login')
```

Let me explain why you might get error, that is `profile.user` is a `User` instance, not a string. So putting `username` will not work. But you can get the user object when you save the form. Like `user=form.save()`, so use that in `profile.user`.

Comment: I tried this, When I try to print profile.StudentID, it gives correct output
but in database nothing is saved
moreover I am getting an error whenever I try to create a new user
IntegrityError at /register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile.user_id